# Failed to launch javafx jar on Max OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, javafx, executable-jar

I am running Mac OS X 10.7.5 on VMware player.

I have installed these on my system -

1. I have jdk-7u12-ea-bin-b07-macosx-x86_64-27_dec_2012.dmg
2. jre-7u10-macosx-x64.dmg
3. netbeans-7.2.1-ml-javase-macosx.dmg

I have set java Java Home pointing to java 1.7. On command prompt it showing version as -

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_12-ea-b07)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b28, mixed mode)

Whenener I am trying to run a jar file created from my JavaFX application. It throw this fatal error on commd prompt-

> ```
> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff88a54fdf, pid=404, tid=18947
>
> # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_12-b07) (build 1.7.0_12-ea-b07)
>
> # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b28 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> # Problematic frame:
>
> # C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x9fdf]  objc_msgSend_fixup+0x5f
> ```
>
> # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To
>   enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java
>   again
>
> ```
> # An error report file with more information is saved as:
>
> # /Users/User/Desktop/JavaFX/hs_err_pid404.log
>
> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>
> #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>
> # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>
> # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>
>
> Abort trap: 6
> ```

Details of fatal error while ex
http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/jarerrorlog.log

On launching netbeans it producing this fatal error -
http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/hs_err_while%20_running_netbeans.log

On opening Java Preferences from System Preferences it showing this fatal erros -
http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/javapreferences.log

I am unable to do anything on Mac OS X, how can I get rid of this errors ?

Comment: I have tried same configuration on Mac OS X 10.8.2, still getting same issues :(

Comment: I've got the same problem, I think it has something to do with os x lacking proper video support in vmware

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the EA jdk and use a released version.

Comment: has nothing to do with EA or not, I tried it with several versions

Answer (score 0):

I logged an issue for this problem: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28144

Answer (score 0):

Neelam, all you need is to change the `prism.order` system property BEFORE JavaFX loads your `javafx.application.Applcation` class.

If your class with `public static void main(String[])` extends the `javafx.application.Application` class then move the `main(String[])` method to another class, `Main.java` for example.

2) Add to your `main(String[])` method some code that changes the `prism.order` property to `"sw"` (software rendering), for example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivelegedAction<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void run() {
                Properties props = System.getProperties();
                props.put("prism.order", "sw");
                Application.launch(YourApplication.class);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also use -Dprism.order=sw when starting app.